# How to style this list to make the it look like a pyramide

Tags: php, html, css

My Array:

```
 array (

       array(

         ['name'] => 'test1',
         ['level'] => 1

       },
       array(

         ['name'] => 'test2',
         ['level'] => 2

       },

       array(

         ['name'] => 'test3',
         ['level'] => 2

       },
       array(

         ['name'] => 'test4',
         ['level'] => 3

       },
       array(

         ['name'] => 'test5',
         ['level'] => 3

       },
       array(

         ['name'] => 'test6',
         ['level'] => 3

       },
       array(

         ['name'] => 'test7',
         ['level'] => 3

       },



    )
```

What I want:

```
                  ________  
                 |        | 
                 |  test1 | 
                 |________| 
       ________              ________
      |        |            |        |
      |  test2 |            |  test3 |
      |________|            |________|
 ________   ________   ________   ________
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|  test4 | |  test5 | |  test6 | |  test7 |
|________| |________| |________| |________|
```

and I already have a function to render by levels:

```
public static function f($rows)
{
    $str = '';
    $level = 0;
    $first_li_mode = true;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($level > $row['level']) {
            $str .= '</li></ul>' . "\n";
            $str .= '</li><li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>' . "\n";
            $first_li_mode = true;
        } elseif ($row['level'] > $level) {
            $str .= '<ul><li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>' . "\n";
            $first_li_mode = false;
            ;
        } else {
            if (!$first_li_mode) {
                $str .= '</li>' . "\n";
            } else {
                $first_li_mode = false;
            }
            $str .= '<li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>' . "\n";
        }

        $level = $row['level'];
    }
    while ($level > 0) {
        $str .= '</li></ul>' . "\n";
        $level--;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

What it produces:

```
<ul>
  <li class="level_1">
  <a href="#">
  test1
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li class="level_2">
     <a href="">test2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="level_3">
     <a href="">test3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and so on..., lets say every parent has 2 childs in this list, the question is: How to style this list to make it look like a pyramide, making every parent node(relative to childs) to appear in the top-middle of them both, as in the diagram above? regardless of depth level, maybe I need to make some calculation in my render function to make an offset every level?, but how?

Comment: I'dont know how to calculate the offset of the children , can you give me a hint on how to calculate it in my loop? I just need some css help in this case

Comment: I have tried: margin-left: ($row['level'] * 20)px;, but this doesn't worked for me, please any ideas? I just don't know how to style it right

Comment: You need to count the number of item in each level, then calculate the offset from there. best to use percentage in css

Comment: You would probably be best just setting `text-align:center` on a parent element and figuring/setting the spacing between the boxes.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Okay, what is the algorithm to setting/figuring the boxes? if I calculate: (count($rows) * 5), the children always be more spaced than the parents

Comment: You would want to use 1/count($rows) as the base unit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try. You may need to adjust the output a bit, see if it would work for you.

```
$sorted_arr=array();
foreach ($arr as $a){
    $sorted_arr[$a['level']][]=$a['name']
}
ksort($sorted_arr);
$css="";
foreach ($sorted_arr as $level => $s){
    $count=count($s);
// First count the number of elements in each level. 
    $spacing=1/($count+1)*100-5; 
// Get the percentage of the offset, then minus the 1/2 width of each li element ( say 10% )
    $css.=".level_$level li {margin-left:".$spacing."%; width:10%} \n";
}
echo $css;
```

Comment: can't understand how this works, the children blocks are margined more than the parents, please can you give a bit more described example?, I'am confused

Comment: the 1/($count+1) should make it become invert relationship. 1 item give you 50%, 2 item give you 33% and so on..

Comment: Maaan my pyramide breaks using this code, I'am trying the whole day to do this, still no luck, please can you give an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ - here or add more details to your answer?